# questions about learning Data Structures and Algorithms in a specific language (noob question)

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, data-structures

just some background info - I have a basic understanding of python after self-teaching myself for a couple of weeks. I am a complete noobie and haven't created a project yet.

The next step for me is trying to learn DS and A. However, one of the resources that Im looking at to learn DS and A is in JavaScript. After looking at what others had to say, most recommend that it doesn't matter what programming language the DS and A resource is in because the goal is to understand the concept. However, to what extent is this true?

Would I be able to easily translate and implement what I've learned from a JavaScript DS and A course to a project in Python? Or should I just find a resource in Python?

Also, just a more general question - how is learning data structures and algorithms useful and utilized in python or any other language? Would someone be able to start creating projects without an understanding of data structures and algorithms and just an understanding of a programming language?

Sorry for the many questions, I am just trying to best prepare myself. I would really appreciate any replies

Comment: Hey, these kind of questions are not really suited for stackoverflow. It is not asking something specific about programming, and different people will have different views on the questions. Data structures are language independent and language is just a tool to implement them. Choose your language and just go with it.

Comment: You can try MIT (free) 6.006 lectures, they use python/pythonish pseudo-code so might be easier for, though in the end language does not matter much. As for why DS & Algorithms is useful - it lets you solve problems efficiently (fast time and/or low space) so you don`t need to buy tons of resources to distribute workload so money gets saved

Answer (score 0):

> Also, just a more general question - how is learning data structures and algorithms useful and utilized in python or any other language?

Knowing Python and/or JavaScript is like being able to lay bricks to make a wall. Data Structures and Algorithms is knowing what kind of wall to put where.